# How to create an event directly in calendar using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am looking to create an event in a users calendar directly. The word directly I mean event should not be going to Inbox. It will appear in calendar directly. And same, if I have to update the event, I should be able to update in users calendar directly not by sending invite. I was able to do this earlier using EWS, but I am unable to do this using Microsoft Graph REST API. My code is running as daemon process having Calendar.ReadWrite Application permission.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried that isn't working? This should be a straightforward process with application permissions.

Comment: There is feature in EWS like,
Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, appointmentId ,.. , ..)
which allows to bind with any appointment in users calendar and can update it, without triggering any update meeting invite in users calendar.
I am not able to find this feature in Microsoft Graph API.

I can create/update/delete event in users calendar using MS Graph API. But in all this case an invite will appear in users Inbox. I want to do update & delete event silently. Should not trigger any invite in users calendar inbox.

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: @AmitPandey were you ever able to find solution for this?